# TypeError: assertEqual() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)

Tags: python-2.7, unit-testing

I am using python 2.7.6, and am trying to create a test case class that inherits from `unittest.TestCase`. I'm having trouble with the `assertEqual`function.

Here's my code:

```
import assignment3 as a3
import unittest
import numpy as np


class a3Testcase(unittest.TestCase):
    """Test for a3 functions"""
    def func_const(self, x):
        return 1

    def func_linear(self, x):
        return x

    def func_quad(self, x):
        return x**2

    def test_gamma_calc(self):
        """determine the Gamma from gamma distribution
        a to b"""
        self.assertAlmostEqual(a3.gamma_calc(self.func_linear, 0, 2), 2)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(a3.gamma_calc(self.func_quad, 0, 1), 1.0/3)

    def test_cal_gamma_array(self):
        """Find the Gamma at mid point of panels a given gamma distribution"""
        panel_coordinates = np.linspace(0, 1, 1+1)
        self.assertEqual((
            a3.calc_gamma_array(panel_coordinates, self.func_const),
            np.array([1.0])))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

And here's the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "test_assignment3.py", line 32, in test_cal_gamma_array
    np.array([1.0])))

TypeError: assertEqual() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

By doing this:

```
self.assertEqual((
        a3.calc_gamma_array(panel_coordinates, self.func_const),
        np.array([1.0])))
```

You are actually passing 2 arguments to `assertEqual`:

- self (because it is an instance method, object is passed as first arg)
- (a3.calc_gamma_array(panel_coordinates, self.func_const),np.array([1.0]))

You need to drop the parentheses to actually pass 3 arguments. Write this instead:

```
self.assertEqual(
        a3.calc_gamma_array(panel_coordinates, self.func_const),
        np.array([1.0]))
```

What is confusing for most people is that there's some parameter number error-compensation between the `self` parameter and the error you made, making the error message difficult to understand: after all, you thought you passed 2 arguments. Who needs 3 arguments? :)